# Launching Fargate Task in private subnet, task being assigned public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have created a Fargate cluster and two task definitions (task1 and task2). Task1 triggers and starts task2. This is all done in a private subnet. I have a problem with task2 being assigned a public ip even though its explicitly defined to be in a private subnet. When task1 tries to ssh into task2 it fails because of the security group does not allow connection to a public ip. Task2 is defined a proper private ip that is within the CIDR of the private subnet. But for some reason task1 seems to prioritize the public ip. Is there some way I can turn off the public ip declaration.

To put ut simply,

Everything is setup using cloudformation:

```
Service:
  Type: AWS::ECS::Service
  Properties:
    ServiceName: !Sub ecs-service-${ServiceName}
    Cluster:
      Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "ecs-cluster-${ServiceName}-Cluster"
    DesiredCount: !Ref DesiredCount
    LaunchType: FARGATE
    TaskDefinition: !Ref RunnerTaskDefinition
    NetworkConfiguration:
      AwsvpcConfiguration:
        AssignPublicIp: DISABLED
        Subnets:
          - !Ref SubnetId
        SecurityGroups:
          - !Ref SecurityGroup

Task1:
  Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
  Properties:
    Family: !Ref ServiceName
    ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref TaskRole
    TaskRoleArn: !Ref TaskRole
    RequiresCompatibilities:
      - FARGATE
    Cpu: !Ref FargateCpu
    Memory: !Ref FargateMemory
    NetworkMode: awsvpc
    ContainerDefinitions:
      - Name: task-1
        Image: !Ref RunnerUri
        PortMappings:
          - ContainerPort: !Ref ContainerPort
          - ContainerPort: 22
          - ContainerPort: 443
        LogConfiguration:
          LogDriver: awslogs
          Options:
            awslogs-group: !Ref ServiceName
            awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
            awslogs-stream-prefix: !Ref ServiceName

Task2:
  Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
  Properties:
    Family: task-2
    ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref TaskRole
    TaskRoleArn: !Ref TaskRole
    RequiresCompatibilities:
      - FARGATE
    Cpu: !Ref FargateCpu
    Memory: !Ref FargateMemory
    NetworkMode: awsvpc
    ContainerDefinitions:
      - Name: task-2
        Image: !Ref CIUri
        PortMappings:
          - ContainerPort: 80
          - ContainerPort: 22
          - ContainerPort: 443
        LogConfiguration:
          LogDriver: awslogs
          Options:
            awslogs-group: !Sub ${ServiceName}-task-2
            awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
            awslogs-stream-prefix: !Sub ${ServiceName}-task-2
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting public IP, because your private subnet has been setup to assign public IPs. You can [disable it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/working-with-vpcs.html#AddaSubnet), as its private subnet, so no reason for this option to be enabled.

Comment: It would make sense if that was the case. But I can clearly see that "Enable auto-assign public IPv4 address" is disabled for my private subnet and enabled for my public subnet. As one would hope.

Comment: @Frankster Then you have to double check your setup. I don't see any other way you could get public IP if you acually have `AssignPublicIp: DISABLED`.

Comment: @Frankster How did it go? Did you double check your setup?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I see what you are saying. But I have double checked both without success. My only explanation is that I don't entirely understand task1 that starts task2. Perhaps it does something I don't understand.

To elaborate, I'm trying ti launch a gitlab runner on fargate task as shown here: https://medium.com/ci-t/serverless-gitlab-ci-cd-on-aws-fargate-da2a106ad39c